# How can I allow only numbers and letters on Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want on the field `name` allow only numbers and letters and on the field `number` only allow numbers.

How I should do it, where can I see a doc where explain it, like my question?

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: null,
    number: null
  },
  methods: {
    checkForm: function (e) {
      if (this.name) {
      return true;
      }
      if (!this.name) {
        console.log("Required");
      }
      if (this.number) {
      return true;
      }
      if (!this.number) {
        console.log("Required");
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<form id="app" @submit="checkForm" method="post" novalidate="true">
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" v-model="name" type="text" name="name">
    <input id="number" v-model="number" type="text" name="number">
  </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just using plain HTML: <input type="number"> will limit to numbers, and the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#htmlattrdefpattern) attribute can be used to specify a regex suitable for the name field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few ways to do this, you can listen to keypress event on the input then check whether the key is letter or number using regex

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    Text & Number Only
    <input type="text" v-model="name" v-on:keypress="isLetterOrNumber($event)">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        name: ""
    }),
    methods: {
        isLetterOrNumber(e) {
            let char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            if (/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(char)) return true;
            else e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

or you can use computed properties to check whether a the input value is letter or number only or not, with this way,  user can still type anything other than number and letter, but it will shows error

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    Text & Number Only (show error):
    <input type="text" v-model="name">
    <div v-if="!nameValid">NOT VALID!!!</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    name: ""
  }),
  computed: {
    nameValid() {
      return /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(this.name);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-meadow-0dns8?file=/src/App.vue:0-651

Comment: Very nice solution!